# httplib will not send any body if the param 'body' of request() is not len()able?

Tags: python, http, post, python-2.7, httplib

Code like this:

```
import httplib
import cStringIO

s = cStringIO.StringIO("hello world") 
c = httplib.HTTPConnection("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
c.request("POST", "/xpost", s)
```

`s` is a read()able object, so request() should send the content of `s`, however, cause the `s` is not len()able, so the data sent by request() does not contain the header `Content-Length` and neither any body content in `body` area.

So, how can I send a POST out while I cannot get the length of the `body` to send?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of `httplib` (at least in Python 2.7) is such that it checks if there is an existing `Content-Length` header before adding one of its own, so if you happen to know the size of the content then you can add your own header - for example:

```
c.request("POST", "/xpost", s, headers={"Content-Length": len(s.getvalue())})
```

If there is no such header, `httplib` tries to call `len()` to fill one in automatically, and if this fails it assumes the body must be a file-like object and calls `os.fstat()` on the OS-level file descriptor to determine its size - it obtains this descriptor by calling the `fileno()` method on the filehandle you've given it. This works fine for real files, but since `StringIO` objects aren't real files they don't provide a `fileno()` method and the operation fails with an `AttributeError`. This error is caught and silently handled by `httplib`, which simply fails to add a `Content-Length`.

If you're definitely using `StringIO` objects, your easiest option is probably to add your own `Content-Length` header as I showed in my example above. If this is just a test while you get things going and you'll be using real files in reality, you can rely on `httplib` to set the header correctly as long as `os.fstat()` works on your platform. If not, you can always call `os.stat()` yourself on the filename and supply your own header in the same way.

If you want to handle both real files and `StringIO` then you can always do something like this:

```
headers = {}
if not hasattr(body, "fileno"):
    headers["Content-Length"] = len(body.getvalue())
```

... But I don't suggest you add that complexity unless you need it.

Finally, at the HTTP level there's another option which is to use [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), where you don't need to supply a `Content-Length` header, the body itself is encoded in self-describing chunks of data. Unfortunately, however, much HTTP software both client and server (`httplib` included) tends to assume that only *responses* will be chunked and *requests* will always use a `Content-Length`. I suppose this assumption is because requests are typically small, but of course with `POST` and `PUT` this assumption doesn't hold water.

Assuming you're confident that your server will handle chunked requests, you could try that - to do so, you'll need to build a `StringIO` object (or anything else with no `fileno()` method to defeat `httplib`'s automatic `Content-Length` insertion) with the chunked encoding already in placed, and supply your own `Transfer-Encoding` header with the value `chunked`. Personally I wouldn't recommend this if you're aiming your software at working with a wide variety of servers.

**EDIT:** As an aside, if you use chunked encoding you *must not* send a `Content-Length` header - see [HTTP RFC §4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) item 3. With a request, of course, you can't signal the end of the body by simply closing the connection because then you'd have no connection on which to receive the response.

As an example of how poor support for chunked requests is, [nginx](http://nginx.org/) only added it to the core functionality in [version 1.3.9](http://nginx.org/2012.html) late last year (although there was [a plugin for it](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule) before that).

**EDIT 2:**

If you read through the Wikipedia article you'll see there's a little more to it than simply sending the right header - you have to split the body into chunks and send each one with a little header consisting of the size of the chunk in hex. This would normally be done for you when sending responses, but as I mentioned support for it in requests is poor.

Here's an example of a wrapper around a file-like object which will convert the body into chunks. I've adapted your example above to show how to use it, although of course the `"hello world"` body is so small it ends up only being a single chunk. It should work for bodies of any size, however. It should work on any object with a `read()` method which works the same way as a Python `file` object. In fact, if you wrap a standard Python file object in one of these it'll prevent `httplib` adding a `Content-Length` because it doesn't support `len()` or `fileno()`.

You still need to remember to add the `Transfer-Encoding` header yourself as shown in my example below:

```
import httplib
import cStringIO

class ChunkedEncodingWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, fileobj, blocksize=8192):
        self.fileobj = fileobj
        self.blocksize = blocksize
        self.current_chunk = ""
        self.closed = False

    def read(self, size=None):
        ret = ""
        while size is None or size >= len(self.current_chunk):
            ret += self.current_chunk
            if size is not None:
                size -= len(self.current_chunk)
            if self.closed:
                self.current_chunk = ""
                break
            self._get_chunk()
        else:
            ret += self.current_chunk[:size]
            self.current_chunk = self.current_chunk[size:]
        return ret

    def _get_chunk(self):
        if not self.closed:
            chunk = self.fileobj.read(self.blocksize)
            if chunk:
                self.current_chunk = "%x" % (len(chunk),) + "\r\n" + chunk + "\r\n"
            else:
                self.current_chunk = "0\r\n\r\n"
                self.closed = True


s = cStringIO.StringIO("hello world")
w = ChunkedEncodingWrapper(s)
c = httplib.HTTPConnection("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
c.request("POST", "/xpost", w, headers={"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a long response :), but I still cannot figure out how to send chunked data by `httplib`, cause the body is an unlen()able stream, so the length of body is not available. I try to add `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to headers, but still fail to send a chunkded body :(

Comment: You need to do more than just add the `Transfer-Encoding` header - please see my second edit above where I've written a wrapper you can put around your stream which will emit chunk-encoded data in a form suitable for `httplib` to consume.